# Reading an innertext from an xml document

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How do I get the innertext of the OverallResult element using SelectSingleNode?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <ProcessResp xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <Result>
            <OverallResult>Success</OverallResult>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var text = doc.SelectSingleNode("Example/Node/text()").InnerText; // or .Value
```

returns

```
"Some text here\r\n    "
```

and text.Trim() returns

```
"Some text here"
```

Please go through the below link for XML related queries its very useful for begginers!

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564

for your answer(i havnt tried it though try by changing like this in ur code)

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("soap/ProcessResp/ Result/OverallResult/text()").InnerText;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to posting questions in statkoverflow. I have added the xml now.